# Tomcat6 in Debian?

Tags: debian, tomcat6

Could someone explain the status of Tomcat6 in Debian to me? My confusion arises from the fact that I can only find a "source" package in Lenny (the stable release) and a "normal"(?) package in Squeeze (testing release). Applicable links:

http://packages.debian.org/source/lenny/tomcat6

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/tomcat6

What is the difference between a source package and 'normal' package? Does this just mean I would have to compile tomcat from source in lenny, but squeeze will have it available to install directly from apt-get? I'm also a bit confused as to why squeeze has a java subsection in its package list but lenny doesnt, although I suppose this might just be a new scheme for the new version?

I hope this is programming related enough for SO, didn't seem like it was applicable for ServerFault. Thanks in advance for bearing with my debian newbieness :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A piece of software (e.g. Tomcat, apache2, GTK+, the kernel) is converted into a source package. A source package combines the original, unmodified source code (as you would download it from the project's webpage) with the build scripts and modifications needed to create the binary ("normal") packages. A source package can create any number of binary packages, which can be either "arch:any" (every processor architecture will have a different version of the package) or "arch:all" (all architectures will share the package). On the source package pages (the ones with `source` in the URL in your question) link to all binary packages built.

From a quick look at the dependencies, it should be possible to install the tomcat 6 packages on a lenny system, using the packages from squeeze.

Make sure the following is in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, or in one of the files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

If `/etc/apt/apt.conf` does not exist, simply create it.

Next, add the squeeze repositories to your `sources.list`, possibly using your local mirror:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
```

Now, update the packages and run

```
apt-get -t testing install tomcat6
```

This should only pull those packages needed for tomcat6, but be careful because newer versions of other packages might be needed, too, so don't try it out on a production machine.

Comment: Please be aware of the problems when using this package; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049371/hibernate-fails-with-nullpointerexception-in-entitytuplizerfactory-constructtupli

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
dget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tomcat6/tomcat6_6.0.16-1.dsc
```

It will download all you need to rebuild the package in Lenny.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the only package that was built from lenny's tomcat6: [libservlet2.5-java](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/libservlet2.5-java). It wasn't indexed from [the search page](http://packages.debian.org/tomcat6), which sucks.